# User creation through a profile for Outlook 2013

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-2013

I would like to create an Outlook 2013 mailbox user with a profile file.
Is there a .prf template that should be OK for Outlook 2013/Exchange 2013 ?

The following command generates the following popup error:

> & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OUTLOOK.EXE' /importprf C:\test2.prf
>
> The connection to Microsoft Exchange is unavailable. Outlook must be online or connected to complete this action.

After clicking on the OK button, the following message is popped up:

> Cannot start Microsoft Outlook. Cannot open the Outlook window. The set of folders cannot be opened. The file C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\test2 - test2.ost is not an Outlook data file (.ost).

Thanks for any help

Simon

test2.prf content:

```
;Automatically generated PRF file from the Microsoft Office Customization and Installation Wizard

; **************************************************************
; Section 1 - Profile Defaults
; **************************************************************

[General]
Custom=1
ProfileName=test2
DefaultProfile=Yes
OverwriteProfile=Append
ModifyDefaultProfileIfPresent=true

; **************************************************************
; Section 2 - Services in Profile
; **************************************************************

[Service List]
;ServiceX=Microsoft Outlook Client
ServiceEGS1=Exchange Global Section
Service1=Microsoft Exchange Server

;***************************************************************
; Section 3 - List of internet accounts
;***************************************************************

[Internet Account List]

;***************************************************************
; Section 4 - Default values for each service.
;***************************************************************

;[ServiceX]
;FormDirectoryPage=
;-- The URL of Exchange Web Services Form Directory page used to create Web forms.
;WebServicesLocation=
;-- The URL of Exchange Web Services page used to display unknown forms.
;ComposeWithWebServices=
;-- Set to true to use Exchange Web Services to compose forms.
;PromptWhenUsingWebServices=
;-- Set to true to use Exchange Web Services to display unknown forms.
;OpenWithWebServices=
;-- Set to true to prompt user before opening unknown forms when using Exchange Web Services.


[ServiceEGS1]
MailboxName=test2@xxxxx
HomeServer=xxxxx
AccountName=test2
ConfigFlags=0x00000100

[Service1]
OverwriteExistingService=No
UniqueService=No
MailboxName=test2@xxxxx
HomeServer=xxxxx

;***************************************************************
; Section 5 - Values for each internet account.
;***************************************************************

;***************************************************************
; Section 6 - Mapping for profile properties
;***************************************************************

[Microsoft Exchange Server]
ServiceName=MSEMS
MDBGUID=5494A1C0297F101BA58708002B2A2517
MailboxName=PT_STRING8,0x6607
HomeServer=PT_STRING8,0x6608
OfflineAddressBookPath=PT_STRING8,0x660E
OfflineFolderPathAndFilename=PT_STRING8,0x6610

[Exchange Global Section]
SectionGUID=13dbb0c8aa05101a9bb000aa002fc45a
MailboxName=PT_STRING8,0x6607
HomeServer=PT_STRING8,0x6608
ConfigFlags=PT_LONG,0x6601
RPCoverHTTPflags=PT_LONG,0x6623
RPCProxyServer=PT_UNICODE,0x6622
RPCProxyPrincipalName=PT_UNICODE,0x6625
RPCProxyAuthScheme=PT_LONG,0x6627
AccountName=PT_UNICODE,0x6620

[Microsoft Mail]
ServiceName=MSFS
ServerPath=PT_STRING8,0x6600
Mailbox=PT_STRING8,0x6601
Password=PT_STRING8,0x67f0
RememberPassword=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6606
ConnectionType=PT_LONG,0x6603
UseSessionLog=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6604
SessionLogPath=PT_STRING8,0x6605
EnableUpload=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6620
EnableDownload=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6621
UploadMask=PT_LONG,0x6622
NetBiosNotification=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6623
NewMailPollInterval=PT_STRING8,0x6624
DisplayGalOnly=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6625
UseHeadersOnLAN=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6630
UseLocalAdressBookOnLAN=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6631
UseExternalToHelpDeliverOnLAN=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6632
UseHeadersOnRAS=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6640
UseLocalAdressBookOnRAS=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6641
UseExternalToHelpDeliverOnRAS=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6639
ConnectOnStartup=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6642
DisconnectAfterRetrieveHeaders=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6643
DisconnectAfterRetrieveMail=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6644
DisconnectOnExit=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6645
DefaultDialupConnectionName=PT_STRING8,0x6646
DialupRetryCount=PT_STRING8,0x6648
DialupRetryDelay=PT_STRING8,0x6649

[Personal Folders]
ServiceName=MSPST MS
Name=PT_STRING8,0x3001
PathAndFilenameToPersonalFolders=PT_STRING8,0x6700 
RememberPassword=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6701
EncryptionType=PT_LONG,0x6702
Password=PT_STRING8,0x6703

[Unicode Personal Folders]
ServiceName=MSUPST MS
Name=PT_UNICODE,0x3001
PathAndFilenameToPersonalFolders=PT_STRING8,0x6700 
RememberPassword=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6701
EncryptionType=PT_LONG,0x6702
Password=PT_STRING8,0x6703

[Outlook Address Book]
ServiceName=CONTAB

[LDAP Directory]
ServiceName=EMABLT
ServerName=PT_STRING8,0x6600
UserName=PT_STRING8,0x6602
UseSSL=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6613
UseSPA=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6615
EnableBrowsing=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6622
DisplayName=PT_STRING8,0x3001
ConnectionPort=PT_STRING8,0x6601
SearchTimeout=PT_STRING8,0x6607
MaxEntriesReturned=PT_STRING8,0x6608
SearchBase=PT_STRING8,0x6603
CheckNames=PT_STRING8,0x6624
DefaultSearch=PT_LONG,0x6623

[Microsoft Outlook Client]
SectionGUID=0a0d020000000000c000000000000046
FormDirectoryPage=PT_STRING8,0x0270
WebServicesLocation=PT_STRING8,0x0271
ComposeWithWebServices=PT_BOOLEAN,0x0272
PromptWhenUsingWebServices=PT_BOOLEAN,0x0273
OpenWithWebServices=PT_BOOLEAN,0x0274
CachedExchangeMode=PT_LONG,0x041f
CachedExchangeSlowDetect=PT_BOOLEAN,0x0420

[Personal Address Book]
ServiceName=MSPST AB
NameOfPAB=PT_STRING8,0x001e3001
PathAndFilename=PT_STRING8,0x001e6600
ShowNamesBy=PT_LONG,0x00036601

; ************************************************************************
; Section 7 - Mapping for internet account properties.  DO NOT MODIFY.
; ************************************************************************

[I_Mail]
AccountType=POP3
;--- POP3 Account Settings ---
AccountName=PT_UNICODE,0x0002
DisplayName=PT_UNICODE,0x000B
EmailAddress=PT_UNICODE,0x000C
;--- POP3 Account Settings ---
POP3Server=PT_UNICODE,0x0100
POP3UserName=PT_UNICODE,0x0101
POP3UseSPA=PT_LONG,0x0108
Organization=PT_UNICODE,0x0107
ReplyEmailAddress=PT_UNICODE,0x0103
POP3Port=PT_LONG,0x0104
POP3UseSSL=PT_LONG,0x0105
; --- SMTP Account Settings ---
SMTPServer=PT_UNICODE,0x0200
SMTPUseAuth=PT_LONG,0x0203
SMTPAuthMethod=PT_LONG,0x0208
SMTPUserName=PT_UNICODE,0x0204
SMTPUseSPA=PT_LONG,0x0207
ConnectionType=PT_LONG,0x000F
ConnectionOID=PT_UNICODE,0x0010
SMTPPort=PT_LONG,0x0201
SMTPSecureConnection=PT_LONG,0x020A
ServerTimeOut=PT_LONG,0x0209
LeaveOnServer=PT_LONG,0x1000

[IMAP_I_Mail]
AccountType=IMAP
;--- IMAP Account Settings ---
AccountName=PT_UNICODE,0x0002
DisplayName=PT_UNICODE,0x000B
EmailAddress=PT_UNICODE,0x000C
;--- IMAP Account Settings ---
IMAPServer=PT_UNICODE,0x0100
IMAPUserName=PT_UNICODE,0x0101
IMAPUseSPA=PT_LONG,0x0108
Organization=PT_UNICODE,0x0107
ReplyEmailAddress=PT_UNICODE,0x0103
IMAPPort=PT_LONG,0x0104
IMAPUseSSL=PT_LONG,0x0105
; --- SMTP Account Settings ---
SMTPServer=PT_UNICODE,0x0200
SMTPUseAuth=PT_LONG,0x0203
SMTPAuthMethod=PT_LONG,0x0208
SMTPUserName=PT_UNICODE,0x0204
SMTPUseSPA=PT_LONG,0x0207
ConnectionType=PT_LONG,0x000F
ConnectionOID=PT_UNICODE,0x0010
SMTPPort=PT_LONG,0x0201
SMTPSecureConnection=PT_LONG,0x020A
ServerTimeOut=PT_LONG,0x0209
CheckNewImap=PT_LONG,0x1100
RootFolder=PT_UNICODE,0x1101
Account=PT_UNICODE,0x0002
HttpServer=PT_UNICODE,0x0100
UserName=PT_UNICODE,0x0101
Organization=PT_UNICODE,0x0107
UseSPA=PT_LONG,0x0108
TimeOut=PT_LONG,0x0209
Reply=PT_UNICODE,0x0103
EmailAddress=PT_UNICODE,0x000C
FullName=PT_UNICODE,0x000B
Connection Type=PT_LONG,0x000F
ConnectOID=PT_UNICODE,0x0010
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it took some time to understand the server name format for Outlook 2013 (well explained in http://www.techieshelp.com/exchange-2013-clients-numbers-instead-of-server-name/).

After that, the RCP parameters come from a manually created outlook profile.
With the OCT tools, the following profile has been created and it is ok:

```
;Automatically generated PRF file from the Microsoft Office Customization and Installation Wizard

; **************************************************************
; Section 1 - Profile Defaults
; **************************************************************

[General]
Custom=1
ProfileName=%UserName%
DefaultProfile=No
OverwriteProfile=Yes
ModifyDefaultProfileIfPresent=false

; **************************************************************
; Section 2 - Services in Profile
; **************************************************************

[Service List]
;ServiceX=Microsoft Outlook Client
ServiceEGS1=Exchange Global Section
Service1=Microsoft Exchange Server

;***************************************************************
; Section 3 - List of internet accounts
;***************************************************************

[Internet Account List]

;***************************************************************
; Section 4 - Default values for each service.
;***************************************************************

;[ServiceX]
;FormDirectoryPage=
;-- The URL of Exchange Web Services Form Directory page used to create Web forms.
;WebServicesLocation=
;-- The URL of Exchange Web Services page used to display unknown forms.
;ComposeWithWebServices=
;-- Set to true to use Exchange Web Services to compose forms.
;PromptWhenUsingWebServices=
;-- Set to true to use Exchange Web Services to display unknown forms.
;OpenWithWebServices=
;-- Set to true to prompt user before opening unknown forms when using Exchange Web Services.


[ServiceEGS1]
MailboxName=%UserName%
HomeServer=%GUIDMailbox%@%Domain%
AccountName=%UserName%
ConfigFlags=0x00000900
RPCoverHTTPflags=0x002f
RPCProxyServer=%ServerExchangeName%
RPCProxyPrincipalName=msstd:%ServerExchangeName%
RPCProxyAuthScheme=0x0002

[Service1]
OverwriteExistingService=Yes
UniqueService=Yes
MailboxName=%UserName%
HomeServer=%GUIDMailbox%@%Domain%

;***************************************************************
; Section 5 - Values for each internet account.
;***************************************************************

;***************************************************************
; Section 6 - Mapping for profile properties
;***************************************************************

[Microsoft Exchange Server]
ServiceName=MSEMS
MDBGUID=5494A1C0297F101BA58708002B2A2517
MailboxName=PT_STRING8,0x6607
HomeServer=PT_STRING8,0x6608
OfflineAddressBookPath=PT_STRING8,0x660E
OfflineFolderPathAndFilename=PT_STRING8,0x6610

[Exchange Global Section]
SectionGUID=13dbb0c8aa05101a9bb000aa002fc45a
MailboxName=PT_STRING8,0x6607
HomeServer=PT_STRING8,0x6608
ConfigFlags=PT_LONG,0x6601
RPCoverHTTPflags=PT_LONG,0x6623
RPCProxyServer=PT_UNICODE,0x6622
RPCProxyPrincipalName=PT_UNICODE,0x6625
RPCProxyAuthScheme=PT_LONG,0x6627
AccountName=PT_UNICODE,0x6620

[Microsoft Mail]
ServiceName=MSFS
ServerPath=PT_STRING8,0x6600
Mailbox=PT_STRING8,0x6601
Password=PT_STRING8,0x67f0
RememberPassword=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6606
ConnectionType=PT_LONG,0x6603
UseSessionLog=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6604
SessionLogPath=PT_STRING8,0x6605
EnableUpload=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6620
EnableDownload=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6621
UploadMask=PT_LONG,0x6622
NetBiosNotification=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6623
NewMailPollInterval=PT_STRING8,0x6624
DisplayGalOnly=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6625
UseHeadersOnLAN=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6630
UseLocalAdressBookOnLAN=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6631
UseExternalToHelpDeliverOnLAN=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6632
UseHeadersOnRAS=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6640
UseLocalAdressBookOnRAS=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6641
UseExternalToHelpDeliverOnRAS=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6639
ConnectOnStartup=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6642
DisconnectAfterRetrieveHeaders=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6643
DisconnectAfterRetrieveMail=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6644
DisconnectOnExit=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6645
DefaultDialupConnectionName=PT_STRING8,0x6646
DialupRetryCount=PT_STRING8,0x6648
DialupRetryDelay=PT_STRING8,0x6649

[Personal Folders]
ServiceName=MSPST MS
Name=PT_STRING8,0x3001
PathAndFilenameToPersonalFolders=PT_STRING8,0x6700 
RememberPassword=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6701
EncryptionType=PT_LONG,0x6702
Password=PT_STRING8,0x6703

[Unicode Personal Folders]
ServiceName=MSUPST MS
Name=PT_UNICODE,0x3001
PathAndFilenameToPersonalFolders=PT_STRING8,0x6700 
RememberPassword=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6701
EncryptionType=PT_LONG,0x6702
Password=PT_STRING8,0x6703

[Outlook Address Book]
ServiceName=CONTAB

[LDAP Directory]
ServiceName=EMABLT
ServerName=PT_STRING8,0x6600
UserName=PT_STRING8,0x6602
UseSSL=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6613
UseSPA=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6615
EnableBrowsing=PT_BOOLEAN,0x6622
DisplayName=PT_STRING8,0x3001
ConnectionPort=PT_STRING8,0x6601
SearchTimeout=PT_STRING8,0x6607
MaxEntriesReturned=PT_STRING8,0x6608
SearchBase=PT_STRING8,0x6603
CheckNames=PT_STRING8,0x6624
DefaultSearch=PT_LONG,0x6623

[Microsoft Outlook Client]
SectionGUID=0a0d020000000000c000000000000046
FormDirectoryPage=PT_STRING8,0x0270
WebServicesLocation=PT_STRING8,0x0271
ComposeWithWebServices=PT_BOOLEAN,0x0272
PromptWhenUsingWebServices=PT_BOOLEAN,0x0273
OpenWithWebServices=PT_BOOLEAN,0x0274
CachedExchangeMode=PT_LONG,0x041f
CachedExchangeSlowDetect=PT_BOOLEAN,0x0420

[Personal Address Book]
ServiceName=MSPST AB
NameOfPAB=PT_STRING8,0x001e3001
PathAndFilename=PT_STRING8,0x001e6600
ShowNamesBy=PT_LONG,0x00036601

; ************************************************************************
; Section 7 - Mapping for internet account properties.  DO NOT MODIFY.
; ************************************************************************

[I_Mail]
AccountType=POP3
;--- POP3 Account Settings ---
AccountName=PT_UNICODE,0x0002
DisplayName=PT_UNICODE,0x000B
EmailAddress=PT_UNICODE,0x000C
;--- POP3 Account Settings ---
POP3Server=PT_UNICODE,0x0100
POP3UserName=PT_UNICODE,0x0101
POP3UseSPA=PT_LONG,0x0108
Organization=PT_UNICODE,0x0107
ReplyEmailAddress=PT_UNICODE,0x0103
POP3Port=PT_LONG,0x0104
POP3UseSSL=PT_LONG,0x0105
; --- SMTP Account Settings ---
SMTPServer=PT_UNICODE,0x0200
SMTPUseAuth=PT_LONG,0x0203
SMTPAuthMethod=PT_LONG,0x0208
SMTPUserName=PT_UNICODE,0x0204
SMTPUseSPA=PT_LONG,0x0207
ConnectionType=PT_LONG,0x000F
ConnectionOID=PT_UNICODE,0x0010
SMTPPort=PT_LONG,0x0201
SMTPSecureConnection=PT_LONG,0x020A
ServerTimeOut=PT_LONG,0x0209
LeaveOnServer=PT_LONG,0x1000

[IMAP_I_Mail]
AccountType=IMAP
;--- IMAP Account Settings ---
AccountName=PT_UNICODE,0x0002
DisplayName=PT_UNICODE,0x000B
EmailAddress=PT_UNICODE,0x000C
;--- IMAP Account Settings ---
IMAPServer=PT_UNICODE,0x0100
IMAPUserName=PT_UNICODE,0x0101
IMAPUseSPA=PT_LONG,0x0108
Organization=PT_UNICODE,0x0107
ReplyEmailAddress=PT_UNICODE,0x0103
IMAPPort=PT_LONG,0x0104
IMAPUseSSL=PT_LONG,0x0105
; --- SMTP Account Settings ---
SMTPServer=PT_UNICODE,0x0200
SMTPUseAuth=PT_LONG,0x0203
SMTPAuthMethod=PT_LONG,0x0208
SMTPUserName=PT_UNICODE,0x0204
SMTPUseSPA=PT_LONG,0x0207
ConnectionType=PT_LONG,0x000F
ConnectionOID=PT_UNICODE,0x0010
SMTPPort=PT_LONG,0x0201
SMTPSecureConnection=PT_LONG,0x020A
ServerTimeOut=PT_LONG,0x0209
CheckNewImap=PT_LONG,0x1100
RootFolder=PT_UNICODE,0x1101
Account=PT_UNICODE,0x0002
HttpServer=PT_UNICODE,0x0100
UserName=PT_UNICODE,0x0101
Organization=PT_UNICODE,0x0107
UseSPA=PT_LONG,0x0108
TimeOut=PT_LONG,0x0209
Reply=PT_UNICODE,0x0103
EmailAddress=PT_UNICODE,0x000C
FullName=PT_UNICODE,0x000B
Connection Type=PT_LONG,0x000F
ConnectOID=PT_UNICODE,0x0010
```

Regards

Simon Elbaz